# how to trigger button click event inside listview with jquery in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, listview

This is my ListView control:

```
<asp:ListView ID="PortfolioListView" runat="server" onitemcommand="PortfolioListView_ItemCommand">
  <ItemTemplate>
    <li class="item brick1 <%# Eval(" CategoryName ")%> isotope-item">
      <a class="item-popup" href="Gallery/195x195/<%# Eval(" MainImage ") %>" title="<%# Eval(" ShortDesc ") %>">
        <img src="Gallery/195x195/<%# Eval("MainImage") %>" alt="<%# Eval("Title") %>" />
        <div class="hover">
           <span class="Popup">
            <i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i>
          </span>
           <span><%# Eval("CategoryName")%></span>
        </div>
      </a>
      <div class="bottom">
        <div class="isotope-title"><span><%# Eval("Title")%></span>
        </div>
        <div class="like">
          <a class="update">
            <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i>
            <span><%# Eval("Counter")%></span>
          </a>
          <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
              <div class="flike">
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LikeLBTN" runat="server" CssClass="likeBTN" ClientIDMode="AutoID" CommandName="Like" CommandArgument="<%# Bind('GalleryID') %>">
                  <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i>
                  <span><%# Eval("Counter")%></span>
                </asp:LinkButton>
              </div>
            </ContentTemplate>
          </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

I have a LinkButton inside ListView and `onitemcommand` event of listview trigger by `LinkButton(CommandName="Like" CommandArgument="<%# Bind('GalleryID') %>")`.

My PortfolioListView_ItemCommand in aspx.cs:

```
protected void PortfolioListView_ItemCommand(object sender, ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    DBClass dbc = new DBClass();
    int index = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
    string cmd = e.CommandName;
    if (cmd == "Like")
    {
        string selstr = String.Format("Update Gallery set [Counter]=[Counter]+1 where GalleryID = {0}", index.ToString());
        int res = dbc.RunCommand(selstr);
        selstr = String.Format("SELECT GalleryID, Title, MainImage, Counter, ShortDesc, CategoryName FROM Gallery inner join GalleryCat on Gallery.CatID = GalleryCat.CatID Order By PDate desc");
        dbc.LoadInList(PortfolioListView, selstr);
    }
}
```

I want when click on `a` tag with `class="update"` in ListView, Click event of LinkButton trigger and my code in PortfolioListView_ItemCommand event be run. Now How this should be done with jquery or javascript? Thank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually client ID of an element is different than the id assigned at server. So try fetching clientId first and then try to trigger click.

```
document.getElementById('<%= LikeLBTN.ClientID %>').click
```

You can navigate to specific `linkButton` using class in `div`.

Following is a sample code using HTML elements:

```js
$(document).on("click", ".update", function() {
  var aTag = $(this);
  var contentPanel = $(aTag).next().find(".contentPanel");
  var flike = $(contentPanel).find(".flike");
  var linkBtn = $(flike).find('.linkBtn');
  linkBtn.click();
})

$(document).on("click", ".linkBtn", function() {
  console.warn("Button clicked");
})
```

```css
div {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="update">Link</a>
<div class="updatePanel">
  <div class="contentPanel">
    <div class="flike">
      <button class="linkBtn">Button</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: when i use your code, I am faced with error Because my LinkButton inside ListView. Do you have another solution?

Comment: There will be more than one linkButton, so which one do you want to call?

Comment: I want when click on class update, my code on server side in PortfolioListView_ItemCommand be run. So all LinkButton.

Comment: @MortezaKarimi I have updated my answer. This approach uses HTML elements but you can use it as reference and implement in your code

Answer (score 0):

> I want when click on 'A' tag with class="update" in ListView, Click event of LiunkButton trigger

Try to add click event to tag a with class `update` then when the user click you can trigger another click on tag with id `#LikeLBTN` :

```
$('body').on('click', '.update', function(){
     $('#LikeLBTN').click();
})
```

Or i suggest to use another hidden link like :

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="SomeControl" onclick="someControlClicked"
  style="display:none; />
```

And instead of `$('#LikeLBTN').click();` you can call `$('#SomeControl').click();`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank bro, But my LinkButton inside ListView and your code does not work. I want when click on class update, my code on server side in PortfolioListView_ItemCommand be run. Do you have another solution? Thank